# Select all items in a table and display them in order depending on their parent Id's

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I have an item table, a type table, and a department table. I need to select all items which is pretty easy, but I want to sort them by department and type and then display them in that order with the headers of their type and department.

I would want to sort them by the Department "Column" value first (there will be 3 columns on the webpage). Then order the departments in each column by the "Order" value of each. Then sort each Type by "CreatedDate" (which is the same as the first added item's created date). Then sort each item under each type by the "CreatedDate" of that item.

Again I can easily do a select * from departments, and then foreach of those do a select of types, and then foreach a select of items, but it is messy and slow when I have thousands of items.

Tables:

```
Items - Id, Type_Id, Title, CreatedDate
Types - Id, Department_Id, Title, CreatedDate
Departments - Id, Title, Column, Order
```

Example Data:

```
Items
1 - 1 - "Apple" - 05/29/2010
2 - 2 - "Corn" - 05/28/2010
3 - 1 - "Orange" - 05/27/2010
4 - 3 - "Beef" - 05/22/2010
5 - 4 - "Screwdriver" - 05/22/2010
6 - 4 - "Hammer" - 05/23/2010
7 - 1 - "Banana" - 05/24/2010
8 - 5 - "Lamp" - 05/22/2010
9 - 6 - "Fork" - 09/26/2013
10 - 6 - "Spoon" - 09/27/2013

Types
1 - 1 - "Fruit" - 05/24/2010
2 - 1 - "Vegetable" - 05/28/2010
3 - 1 - "Meat" - 05/22/2010
4 - 2 - "Handtools" - 05/22/2010
5 - 4 - "Lighting" - 05/22/2010
6 - 3 - "Utensils" - 09/26/2013

Departments
1 - "Food" - 1 - 1
2 - "Tools" - 2 - 1
3 - "Kitchen" - 3 - 2
4 - "Living Room" - 3 - 1
```

This would display like the following in actual columns by divs or a table:

---

## Column 1

**Food**

1. **Meat**

   - Beef
2. **Fruit**

   - Banana
   - Orange
   - Apple
3. **Vegetable**

   - Corn

---

## Column 2

**Tools**

1. **Handtools**

   - Screwdriver
   - Hammer

---

## Column 3

**Living Room**

1. **Lighting**

   - Lamp

**Kitchen**

1. **Utensils**

   - Fork
   - Spoon

---

Comment: So, which part of that are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to start off with properly joining all of the tables together to get one large conglomerate of data and then use PHP to check when to display a different header:

```
SELECT
    i.Title,
    t.Title,
    d.Title
FROM
    Items i
    LEFT JOIN Types t
        ON i.type_id = t.Id
    LEFT JOIN Departments d
        ON t.Department_Id = d.Id
ORDER BY
    d.Column ASC,
    d.Order ASC,
    t.CreateDate ASC,
    i.CreateDate ASC
```

Comment: Glad I could help, if you get stuck with the logic for differentiating the headers in PHP just let me know!